# Updating label binding with property isn't setting right the first time

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have a simple application, and i'm trying to get a grasp on binding, and properties.

What I'm trying to do:
Load a modal window, from the main window. I know this blocks all access to it, so I'm trying to update a label on the modal window through a property binding.

I set the datacontext:

```
   DataContext = busyupdate
   InitializeComponent()
```

Set the variable:

```
Property busyupdate As BusyWindowGetSet = New BusyWindowGetSet
```

Then I bind the label to the current context:

```
Content="{Binding Stage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Content="{Binding Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Here is my BusyWindowGetSet class, where I have 2 properties... Stage and Description. It implements INotifyPropertyChanged

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class BusyWindowGetSet

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Property Stage() As String
        Get
            Return m_stage
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_stage = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Stage")
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared m_Stage As String

    Public Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return m_description
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_description = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description")
        End Set
    End Property
    Private Shared m_Description As String

#Region "INotifyPropertyChanged Members"
    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
#End Region

#Region "Private Helpers"
    Public Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub
#End Region

End Class
```

When I load the "busy window" the labels are not updated.. but If I load the window a second time, they show up and change like normal.

This is how I'm setting the properties...

```
busyupdate.Stage = String.Format("Stage: {0}", "Warming up1")
busyupdate.Description = String.Format("Description: {0}", "Warming up1")
```

What am I missing here?

Update for Mark:

```
    Dim mm As New BusyWindow
    mm.ShowDialog()

    busyupdate.Stage = String.Format("Stage: {0}", "Warming up1")
    busyupdate.Description = String.Format("Description: {0}", "Warming up1")
```

Comment: Just guessing... try removing the `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from your bindings.  At a glance, everything else seems ok - and you probably don't want to update the source property from a label, if that's even possible.

Comment: I just added that, because i'm grasping at straws as to why this isn't working. It doesn't work with or without it... the first time anyway. The second time is still fine, both ways ><.

Comment: The only other thing I usually do differently is set the DataContext after the InitializeComponent call, although I can't imagine that would make any difference.

Comment: Perhaps if you show the code where you are showing the modal window and settings the properties...

Comment: Updated the OP.

Comment: Ah, ok... so `ShowDialog` will block until the modal is closed, so the lines setting the properties are not called until after the modal is gone.  Move the `mm.ShowDialog()` line to after you set the properties and see if that helps.

Comment: It does, but that defeats what i'm trying to do. Perhaps I need to be doing something different. I'm trying to block mouse clicks to the main window, when the second child window is open. That's why i'm using a modal window instead of just using .show.

Comment: What if you try disabling the main window yourself? You could disable the new window's parent the `Loaded` event, and then enable it again in the `Closing` event.

Comment: Good suggestion, but they can still close and move the main window when I do that.

Comment: You can? I didn't know that. I'm not very familiar with WPF but you can't do so in WinForms.

Comment: Yea, I came from VB, and don't get it either.